# boto3: Spot Instance Creation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, boto3

I'm trying to create a spot instance using boto3. Although I follow the [API documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.request_spot_instances), I receive an exception I couldn't be able to figure out. The code I'm using is:

```
import boto3
import datetime
client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.request_spot_instances(
    DryRun=False,
    SpotPrice='0.10',
    ClientToken='string',
    InstanceCount=1,
    Type='one-time',
    LaunchSpecification={
        'ImageId': 'ami-fce3c696',
        'KeyName': 'awskey.pem',
        'SecurityGroups': ['sg-709f8709'],
        'InstanceType': 'm4.large',
        'Placement': {
            'AvailabilityZone': 'us-east-1a',
        },
        'BlockDeviceMappings': [
            {
                'Ebs': {
                    'SnapshotId': 'snap-f70deff0',
                    'VolumeSize': 100,
                    'DeleteOnTermination': True,
                    'VolumeType': 'gp2',
                    'Iops': 300,
                    'Encrypted': False
                },
            },
        ],

        'EbsOptimized': True,
        'Monitoring': {
            'Enabled': True
        },
        'SecurityGroupIds': [
            'sg-709f8709',
        ]
    }
)
```

And I receive the following exception:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the RequestSpotInstances operation: Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty
```

The thing is there is no groupId parameter in the request in the [API documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.request_spot_instances).

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you specifying both `SecurityGroups` and `SecurityGroupIds`? It looks like you only would need `SecurityGroupIds` as you are passing the sg id rather than the name.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Although it's not specified in the API documentation, apparently 'SecurityGroups' parameter requires the names of the security groups, not the IDs.

Changing to the group name solved the issue.

Thanks for anyone bothered to read the question in the first place.

Comment: This just saved me hours.

Comment: Do you need both `SecurityGroups` and `SecurityGroupIds`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with security group ids it is working fine.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import boto3

session=boto3.session.Session(profile_name="*****")
ec2instances=session.resource('ec2',region_name="********")
new_instance = ec2instances.create_instances(
        ImageId = 'ami-04125d804acca5692',
        MinCount = 1,
        MaxCount = 1,
        InstanceType = 't2.micro',
        KeyName ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        SecurityGroupIds=['sg-05dec40ce8b91a8c8'],
        SubnetId = 'subnet-01ca807d148d9e328'
)
print(new_instance)
```

Comment: The original question was about spot requests, not on-demand requests.